# Is downloadOnly synchronous or asynchronous in Android Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

Consider the following line of code:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).downloadOnly().load(some_uri).submit();
```

**Question 1)** Is the above synchronous or asynchronous?

**Question 2)** If the above is synchronous, then how do I make it asynchronous?

**Question 3)** If the above is asynchronous, then how do I make it synchronous?

The question refers specifically to the Glide version 4 API.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answering my own question.

```
Glide.with(getContext()).downloadOnly().load(some_uri).submit();
```

is asynchronous.

```
Glide.with(getContext()).downloadOnly().load(some_uri).submit().get();
```

is synchronous.

Comment: Good ! Can you specify source of the info. I was trying help you but can't find this in documentation .

Comment: @MishaAkopov one of the glide developers answered. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2775. This was further tested by myself by including a simple Log.d(...) statement and checking if all requests came back in order

Comment: Ahh, so sad they don't have such things in documentation.

Comment: @MishaAkopov I think the documentation that you referred to already explained my question. However, since it was using a slightly different method signature, and because it did not explicitly state it, it made me uncomfortable and paranoid

Answer (score 0):

Glide's downloadOnly() API allows you to download the bytes of an image into the disk cache so that it will be available to be retrieved later. You can use downloadOnly() asynchronously **downloadOnly(Y target)** on the ui thread or synchronously **donwloadOnly(int, int)** on a background thread. Note that the arguments are slightly different, the asynchronous api takes a Target and the synchronous api takes an integer width and height.

To download images on a background thread, you must use the synchronous version:

```
FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(applicationContext)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .downloadOnly(500, 500);
File cacheFile = future.get();
```

Once the future returns, the bytes of the image are available in the cache. Typically the downloadOnly() API is only used to make sure the bytes are available on disk. Although you are given access to the underlying cache File, you usually don’t want to interact with it.

Instead when you later want to retrieve your image, you can do so using a normal call with one exception:

```
Glide.with(yourFragment)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(yourView);
```

Comment: This is outdated (v3). I am interested in (v4). The developers deprecated certain methods (the ones you referenced), and has since substituted in new ones. The reason I am asking is because I have already read all available documentation on it and didn't find what I need.

Comment: Ah. Ok, now I see you want v4.